# How can I get the account associated to a meeting request?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I need to know the  account email address a meeting request is associated to (the email address the meeting request is sent to):

```
string GetAssociatedAccountEmailAddress(Outlook.MeetingItem meetingItem)
{
    //TODO: implement this method:
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

This is what I tried:

```
string GetAssociatedAccountEmailAddress1(Outlook.MeetingItem meetingItem)
{
    Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = meetingItem.Parent;
    Debug.WriteLine("Folder Name: {0}, Folder Path: {1}", folder.Name, folder.FolderPath);

    Outlook.MAPIFolder folderParent = folder.Parent;
    Debug.WriteLine("Folder Parent Name: {0}, Folder Parent Path: {1}", folderParent.Name, folderParent.FolderPath);

    return folderParent.FolderPath.Replace("\\", "");
}
```

Debug output:

```
Folder Name: Inbox, Folder Path: \\\\foo@foo.com\Inbox
Folder Parent Name: foo@foo.com, Folder Parent Path: \\\\foo@foo.com
```

The problem with this implementation is that I'm not sure the folder path will always contain the email address.

I also tried the following:

```
string GetAssociatedAccountEmailAddress2(Outlook.MeetingItem meetingItem)
{
    Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = meetingItem.Parent;

    Outlook.MAPIFolder folderParent = folder.Parent;

    Outlook.NameSpace ns = folderParent.Parent;
    return ns.Accounts.Cast<Outlook.Account>()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => meetingItem.Recipients.Cast<Outlook.Recipient>().Any(r => r.Address == x.SmtpAddress))
        .SmtpAddress;
}
```

The problem with this is that if I have two accounts (foo@foo.com and bar@bar.com) and the meeting request is sent to both, then I have two meeting requests but `GetAssociatedAccountEmailAddress2` returns the same email address.

FYI: I'm developing an Outlook add-in for Outlook 2013 using VS 2015.

Comment: Well, both meeting requests have the same recipients, so no wonder you get the same result - your code returns the first matching address. You need to look at the parent store and figure out its owner.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko. The parent of what? I look at the parent on GetAssociatedAccountEmailAddress1 but it doesn't seem to be the right way? Could you elaborate? please.

Comment: I meant the parent store of the folder where the meeting request lives.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko how can I figure out the store owner account? I cannot find a direct relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple ways to do that -

1. Read the `PR_RECEIVED_BY_ENTRYID` property (not guaranteed to be present, DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x003F0102`) using `MeetingItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`, convert it to a hex string using `PropertyAccessor.BinaryToString`, use it to call `Application.Session.GetAddressEntryFromID`. Note that the property might not match the actual store owner if the item was copied from another store. Take a look at the meeting request with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its authot) - click IMessage button to see that property.
2. Read the `PR_MAILBOX_OWNER_ENTRYID` property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x661B0102`) from the parent store (`MeetingItem.Parent.Store`) using `Store.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`. The property is not guaranteed to be present. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am also its author) is an option, it exposes the [RDOExchangeMailboxStore](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm) object that has the `Owner` property (returns [RDOAddressEntry](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAddressEntry.htm) object).

Comment: Thanks. The first one worked for me. I think I would need to try both and fallback to something if neither work.